# TMG matlab tool error

Tags: matlab

I am trying to generate a tf-idf representation of a text file using TMG matlab tool.

This is how I set up my variables:

[image]

When I press continue, I get the following error.

> Undefined function or variable 'new_sprintf'.
>
> Error in tmg_p
>
> Error in tmg (line 124)
>       if nargout==8, [varargout{1}, varargout{2}, varargout{3}, varargout{4}, varargout{5}, varargout{6}, varargout{7},
>       varargout{8}]=tmg_p(varargin{1}, varargin{2}); end
>
> Error in tmg_gui>ContinueButton_Callback (line 456)
>       [A, dictionary, global_weights, normalization_factors, words_per_doc, titles, files, update_struct]=tmg(filename, OPT);
>
> Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
>           feval(varargin{:});
>
> Error in tmg_gui (line 27)
>       gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
>
> Error in
>   matlab.graphics.internal.figfile.FigFile/read>@(hObject,eventdata)tmg_gui('ContinueButton_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
>   Error while evaluating UIControl Callback

And the environment path changes to: log_files

What's causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem, but installing MATLAB 2013a or 2012b and using an earlier verion of tmg solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too: you have to add the path of TMG to MATLAB before using it.

[image]